# How do I extract value of XML attribute in Python?

Tags: python, xml

I need to extract the value of an attribute in an XML document using Python.

For example, If I have an XML document like this:

```
<xml>
    <child type = "smallHuman"/>
    <adult type = "largeHuman"/>
</xml>
```

How would I be able get the text 'smallHuman' or 'largeHuman' to store in a variable?

Edit: I'm very new to Python and may require a lot of assistance.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def walkTree(node):
    print node.tag
    print node.keys()
    print node.attributes[]
    for cn in list(node):
        walkTree(cn)

treeOne = ET.parse('tm1.xml')
treeTwo = ET.parse('tm3.xml')

walkTree(treeOne.getroot())
```

Due to the way this script will be used, I cannot hard-code the XML into the .py file.

Comment: The first link in google should help you.

Comment: I've updated the question with the code written so far @James

Comment: Read more on the ElementTree module. You will get solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using ElementTree you can use **find method** & **attrib** .

**Example:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

z = """<xml>
    <child type = "smallHuman"/>
    <adult type = "largeHuman"/>
</xml>"""


treeOne = ET.fromstring(z)
print treeOne.find('./child').attrib['type']
print treeOne.find('./adult').attrib['type']
```

**Output:**

```
smallHuman
largeHuman
```

Answer (score 8):

To get the attribute value from an XML, you can do like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_data = """<xml>
<child type = "smallHuman"/>
<adult type = "largeHuman"/>
</xml>"""

# This is like ET.parse(), but for strings
root = ET.fromstring(xml_data)

for a child in root:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
```

You can find more details and examples on the link below:
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Answer (score 0):

Another example using lxml library:

```
xml = '''<xml>
    <child type = "smallHuman"/>
    <adult type = "largeHuman"/>
</xml>'''

from lxml import etree as et

root = et.fromstring(xml)

# find attribute using xpath
child_type = root.xpath('//xml/child/@type')[0]
print(child_type)

adult_type = root.xpath('//xml/adult/@type')[0]
print(adult_type)

# combination of find / get
child_type = root.find('child').get('type')
adult_type = root.find('adult').get('type')

print(child_type)
print(adult_type)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example using SimplifiedDoc library:

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils
xml = '''<xml>
    <child type = "smallHuman"/>
    <adult type = "largeHuman"/>
</xml>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml).select('xml')

# first
child_type = doc.child['type']
print(child_type)

adult_type = doc.adult['type']
print(adult_type)

# second
child_type = doc.select('child').get('type')
adult_type = doc.select('adult').get('type')

print(child_type)
print(adult_type)

# second
child_type = doc.select('child>type()')
adult_type = doc.select('adult>type()')

print(child_type)
print(adult_type)

# third
nodes = doc.selects('child|adult>type()')
print(nodes)
# fourth
nodes = doc.children
print ([node['type'] for node in nodes])
```